# Translation: Tempus Medendi

Tags: translation-check

I am hopeful someone may be able to assist me with a translation please :)

I am trying to find numerous ways to say: ‘the season of healing’ or ‘time of healing’ in Latin..

I found ‘Tempus Medendi’ in online translations and quite like this, but am not sure it conveys the message accurately..

I’d be so grateful for any advice or assistance :)

Thank you!
Amy

Answer (score 5):

Yes, *tempus medendi* means "time of healing," but not necessarily in the sense you're thinking of.

That's because *medendi* is a form (the so-called gerund) of the verb *mederi*, which really means "help somebody who's sick" or simply "cure." So: *tempus (aegris) medendi* = "time to heal (the sick)" is fine. But I suspect that is not quite what you mean.

On the other hand, if you mean "heal" in the sense of "become healthy, get well," then *mederi* doesn't quite fit. In that case I would suggest the verb *convalescere* instead, yielding: **tempus convalescendi**.

Another option would be *sanescere*, i.e., *tempus sanescendi*. Use whichever sounds best to you.

Comment: Sebastian, thank you so much for your response, this is very helpful! I wonder would there also be a more appropriate word to express ‘season’ of healing then, or does Tempus imply this also? Thanks for taking the time to respond - it’s appreciated:)

Comment: @amyelyn, tempus + gerundive definitely seems to be good choice here.  *Ecclesiastes* Chapter 3 mentions many *tempora*.  at verse 3 you can find also another option for "time to heal" which is "tempus sanandi" (but this is more like *medendi*)

Comment: Ah, this is much clearer to me now. I really appreciate you sharing your knowledge here.. Thank you!  :)

Comment: @d_e Ahaha, great find! [That passage](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecc+3&version=VULGATE) is an absolute gerundium fest :)